# Vagrant provisioning fails

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox

So after I created a similar vm, Vagrant fails to provision:

```
vagrant up
```

...

verbose:

```
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Worker/Apache::Mpm[worker]/File[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.load]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Worker/File[/etc/apache2/mods-available/worker.conf]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}59cf27b20f14393692303b41f3071df6'
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Worker/File[/etc/apache2/mods-available/worker.conf]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Worker/Apache::Mpm[worker]/File[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.conf]/ensure: created
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Worker/Apache::Mpm[worker]/File[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.conf]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/File[cgid.conf]: Filebucketed /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.conf to puppet with sum e8a2836392051bde889cf9c137058273
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/File[cgid.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}e8a2836392051bde889cf9c137058273' to '{md5}7dffbb5823bcbb9ab4d3e67ab14d38a0'
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/File[cgid.conf]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/Apache::Mod[cgid]/File[cgid.conf symlink]/ensure: created
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/Apache::Mod[cgid]/File[cgid.conf symlink]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/Apache::Mod[cgid]/File[cgid.load symlink]/ensure: created
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Cgid/Apache::Mod[cgid]/File[cgid.load symlink]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[default_vhost_80]/Concat::Fragment[default_vhost_80-directories]/File[/var/lib/puppet/concat/10-default_vhost_80.conf/fragments/60_default_vhost_80-directories]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}c0f5d086c1fb77355364fde626855125'
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[default_vhost_80]/Concat::Fragment[default_vhost_80-directories]/File[/var/lib/puppet/concat/10-default_vhost_80.conf/fragments/60_default_vhost_80-directories]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[concat_10-default_vhost_80.conf]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[default_vhost_80]/Concat[10-default_vhost_80.conf]/Exec[concat_10-default_vhost_80.conf]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[default_vhost_80]/Concat[10-default_vhost_80.conf]/Exec[concat_10-default_vhost_80.conf]: Triggered 'refresh' from 9 events
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Default_mods/Apache::Mod[env]/File[env.load symlink]/target: target changed '../mods-available/env.load' to '/etc/apache2/mods-available/env.load'
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Apache::Default_mods/Apache::Mod[env]/File[env.load symlink]: Scheduling refresh of Class[Apache::Service]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Puphpet::Php::Module[intl]/Php::Module[intl]/Package[PhpModule_intl]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Puphpet::Php::Module[intl]/Php::Module[intl]/Package[PhpModule_intl]: Scheduling refresh of Service[php5-fpm]
```

and then it fails somewhere here:

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[php5-fpm]: Triggered 'refresh' from 13 events
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
```

and an error log is being super general

```
The provider for this Vagrant-managed machine is reporting that it
is not yet ready for SSH. Depending on your provider this can carry
different meanings. Make sure your machine is created and running and
try again. Additionally, check the output of `vagrant status` to verify
that the machine is in the state that you expect. If you continue to
get this error message, please view the documentation for the provider
you're using.
```

Machine status:

```
default                   aborted (virtualbox)
```

After I am trying to up it again, the status changes to

```
default                   running (virtualbox)
```

However, an apache2 remains unconfigured.

This exactly machine was working well, up until my computer shut down unexpectedly.

Vagrantfile was configured with puphpet:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: local.puphpet
        memory: '4096'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                vflnp_s2r52zqm9il5:
                    host: '5105'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_jsyjt6qqjv6g:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www/some
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_waoqjnfx3bdq:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_dxl1t6uo4ne5:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                nxvl_sz4s0mdyj1l7:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_3e4zn3m5qrj8:
            servername: rusroads.dev
            docroot: /var/www/some
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_wji3ysov16ho:
                    path: /var/www/some
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_y8f6jikawjc0:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_ljtz845og4bc:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    npm_packages:
        - grunt-cli
        - bower
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mysql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: 'some'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_4ljvghhv688f:
            name: 123
            password: 'some'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_opuz0wjig2wj:
            name: some
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_gapwtqorf5s2:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.3'
        server:
            postgres_password: 'some'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your Vagrantfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similar errors about apache install on Vagrant. In my case it was because Apache's document root did not exist (or was a symbolic link) at the time that Apache was being installed by apt-get.

I was provisioning the guest machine using a bash script that messed with Apache's root before installing Apache, something like this:

```
# Remove /var/www and recreate it as a link to the vagrant root.
rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant/sites /var/www

# Install Apache.
apt-get install -y apache2
```

I was able to fix the problem by reversing the order, installing Apache first then changing it's document root.

Like you, this was on Ubuntu 14.04 and it was also working for me, then suddenly broke.

Sorry I don't know about puphpet. Hope this helps anyway.